# how to select a data set from this array

Tags: php, json, api

```
{
"success" : true,
"message" : "",
"result" : [{
        "PaymentUuid" : "554ec664-8842-4fe9-b491-06225becbd59",
        "Currency" : "BTC",
        "Amount" : 0.00156121,
        "Address" : "1K37yQZaGrPKNTZ5KNP792xw8f7XbXxetE",
        "Opened" : "2014-07-11T03:41:25.323",
        "Authorized" : true,
        "PendingPayment" : false,
        "TxCost" : 0.00020000,
        "TxId" : "70cf6fdccb9bd38e1a930e13e4ae6299d678ed6902da710fa3cc8d164f9be126",
        "Canceled" : false,
        "InvalidAddress" : false
    }, {
        "PaymentUuid" : "d3fdf168-3d8e-40b6-8fe4-f46e2a7035ea",
        "Currency" : "BTC",
        "Amount" : 0.11800000,
        "Address" : "1Mrcar6715hjds34pdXuLqXcju6QgwHA31",
        "O
        pened" : "2014-07-03T20:27:07.163",
        "Authorized" : true,
        "PendingPayment" : false,
        "TxCost" : 0.00020000,
        "TxId" : "3efd41b3a051433a888eed3ecc174c1d025a5e2b486eb418eaaec5efddda22de",
        "Canceled" : false,
        "InvalidAddress" : false
    }
]
```

}

How do I select the data set that contains 
`"TxId":"3efd41b3a051433a888eed3ecc174c1d025a5e2b486eb418eaaec5efddda22de"`

So that I can write an if statement using its payment did. Also, these data sets are going to be in different order every time and with more and more dataset added so cant use number indexing.

How could I do this in PHP thanks in advance.

Comment: as it strands this question is offtopic right now,where is your code?

Comment: did you try anything? please share with us so that we can help you.

Comment: will add it now

Comment: First step.... make it an array rather than a json string

Comment: $obj = json_decode($execResult, true);
    $returned_result = $obj['result']['TxId']; So i used json_decode and using the $obj['result']['TxId'] it just ended up returning the whole json

Comment: $obj['result'] is a 2 dimensional array, so you have to access one of the underlying arrays prior to accessing Txld, also for semantics sake it's best not to call your variable "$obj" when it's an array

Comment: Please add your code to the question not in a comment

Answer (score 2):

Loop thru result array inside your json_decoded array, then check for `TxId`

```
$search = "3efd41b3a051433a888eed3ecc174c1d025a5e2b486eb418eaaec5efddda22de";

$obj = json_decode($execResult, true);

foreach ($obj['result'] as $result) {
    if ($result['TxId'] == $search) {
        // If statement for PaymentUuid here
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `json_decode` to get data and use `foreach` loop.

```html
<?php 
  $string='{
"success" : true,
"message" : "",
"result" : [{
        "PaymentUuid" : "554ec664-8842-4fe9-b491-06225becbd59",
        "Currency" : "BTC",
        "Amount" : 0.00156121,
        "Address" : "1K37yQZaGrPKNTZ5KNP792xw8f7XbXxetE",
        "Opened" : "2014-07-11T03:41:25.323",
        "Authorized" : true,
        "PendingPayment" : false,
        "TxCost" : 0.00020000,
        "TxId" : "70cf6fdccb9bd38e1a930e13e4ae6299d678ed6902da710fa3cc8d164f9be126",
        "Canceled" : false,
        "InvalidAddress" : false
    }, {
        "PaymentUuid" : "d3fdf168-3d8e-40b6-8fe4-f46e2a7035ea",
        "Currency" : "BTC",
        "Amount" : 0.11800000,
        "Address" : "1Mrcar6715hjds34pdXuLqXcju6QgwHA31",
        "O
        pened" : "2014-07-03T20:27:07.163",
        "Authorized" : true,
        "PendingPayment" : false,
        "TxCost" : 0.00020000,
        "TxId" : "3efd41b3a051433a888eed3ecc174c1d025a5e2b486eb418eaaec5efddda22de",
        "Canceled" : false,
        "InvalidAddress" : false
    }
]
}';
$json = json_decode($string, true);
$TxId = "3efd41b3a051433a888eed3ecc174c1d025a5e2b486eb418eaaec5efddda22de";
foreach ($json as $key => $value){
      $txid=$value[1]['TxId'];
      if ($txid == $TxId) {
        // code
      }


    }

 ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
   <?php

$data='{
"success" : true,
"message" : "",
"result" : [{
        "PaymentUuid" : "554ec664-8842-4fe9-b491-06225becbd59",
        "Currency" : "BTC",
        "Amount" : 0.00156121,
        "Address" : "1K37yQZaGrPKNTZ5KNP792xw8f7XbXxetE",
        "Opened" : "2014-07-11T03:41:25.323",
        "Authorized" : true,
        "PendingPayment" : false,
        "TxCost" : 0.00020000,
        "TxId" : "70cf6fdccb9bd38e1a930e13e4ae6299d678ed6902da710fa3cc8d164f9be126",
        "Canceled" : false,
        "InvalidAddress" : false
    }, {
        "PaymentUuid" : "d3fdf168-3d8e-40b6-8fe4-f46e2a7035ea",
        "Currency" : "BTC",
        "Amount" : 0.11800000,
        "Address" : "1Mrcar6715hjds34pdXuLqXcju6QgwHA31",
        "opened" : "2014-07-03T20:27:07.163",
        "Authorized" : true,
        "PendingPayment" : false,
        "TxCost" : 0.00020000,
        "TxId" : "3efd41b3a051433a888eed3ecc174c1d025a5e2b486eb418eaaec5efddda22de",
        "Canceled" : false,
        "InvalidAddress" : false
    }
]
}';


$data=json_decode($data,true);

foreach($data['result'] as $row){

    if(array_search("3efd41b3a051433a888eed3ecc174c1d025a5e2b486eb418eaaec5efddda22de",$row,true)){
        echo '<pre>';
         print_r($row);
         echo '</br>';
    }

}
```

First of all your json was not valid. I fixed it in order to make it work, you had typo in the second array in the *opened* but i guess it's just a typo nothing more. So this code will get you the results you need. As the results you seek are nested you need to follow their "path" in order to reach them so you have to access first the parent array etc etc

***UPDATE**

I modified my code to search for the value you asked in the description, i missed that part. Now it's working as you wish the output is:

```
Array
(
    [PaymentUuid] => d3fdf168-3d8e-40b6-8fe4-f46e2a7035ea
    [Currency] => BTC
    [Amount] => 0.118
    [Address] => 1Mrcar6715hjds34pdXuLqXcju6QgwHA31
    [opened] => 2014-07-03T20:27:07.163
    [Authorized] => 1
    [PendingPayment] => 
    [TxCost] => 0.0002
    [TxId] => 3efd41b3a051433a888eed3ecc174c1d025a5e2b486eb418eaaec5efddda22de
    [Canceled] => 
    [InvalidAddress] => 
)
```